# What's the difference between for all x in S, for all y in S and for all y in S, for all x in S?

Tags: logic

I need to prove the following and I want to know the difference between "for all x in S, for all y in S" & "for all y in S,for all x in S" i.e. the difference between $\forall x\in S\forall y\in S$ and $\forall y\in S\forall x\in S$

For a given predicate $p$ defined on $S^2$, prove that:

$$\forall x\in S\forall y\in S [p(x,y)] \iff \forall y\in S\forall x\in S [p(x,y)]$$

Comment: I guess the question is asking you to prove that "For all x in S, for all y in S" is same as "for all y in S, for all x in S".

Comment: Yes, can you prove it?

Comment: Use [Universal instantiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) on x and y and then [Universal generalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalization_(logic)).

Comment: @S.Dan Are you supposed to prove this in a formal system? If you are, what is your system? What are your deduction rules.

Comment: No there is no formal system. I want to know how the meaning is altered when x and y are interchanged.

Comment: It's not altered, the statements are equivalent.

Comment: Then what do I have to prove? I'm kinda confused

Comment: You're not proving anything about meanings. You're proving, in effect, that the formal rules agree with your intuition that quantifier order doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not work with a "formal" *proof system* (e.g.axioms and rules) and you do not state a "formal" *semantics*, you cannot prove it.

You can only "argument" informally.

Try with, for example : $\forall x \forall y (x < y)$ and interpret it in the *domain* $\mathbb N$ of *natural numbers*.

Are you able to find a differt meaning with :  $\forall y \forall x (x < y)$ ?

The way you can argument for the validity of this law is this.

Consider a domain $D$ whatever; because we have $\forall x \forall y P(x,y)$, if we pick an object $a \in D$ whatever, we have that $\forall y P(a,y)$ holds.

This means that for an object $b \in D$ whatever, $P(a,b)$ holds.

But if $P(a,b)$ holds for an object $a \in D$ whatever, we may conclude that $\forall x P(x,b)$ holds.

The last sentence holds for an object $b \in D$ whatever, which means that $\forall y \forall x P(x,y)$ holds.

This argument holds for a *domain* $D$ whatever. Thus it applies to every (non empty) domain.

But, having shown that, for every domain, if $\forall x \forall y P(x,y)$ holds, then $\forall y \forall x P(x,y)$ holds, we are licensed to conclude (informally) with the *validity* of the implication :

> $\vDash \forall x \forall y P(x,y) \rightarrow \forall y \forall x P(x,y)$.

The reasoning works in the same way "reversing" the order of the formulae; thus, we conclude with :

> > $\vDash \forall x \forall y P(x,y) \leftrightarrow \forall y \forall x P(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I sort of started to get it.